# Network unreachable while know IP and PORT

Tags: networking, socketexception

i have a problem with error "Network unreachable"

this is error message i got

```
04-01 23:39:06.455: E/ClientActivity(1932): Client Send Error:/192.168.1.25444
04-01 23:39:06.455: W/System.err(1932): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 23:39:06.463: W/System.err(1932):     at edu.dongthang.controller.AppDelegate$ClientThread.sendMessage(AppDelegate.java:93)
04-01 23:39:06.463: W/System.err(1932):     at edu.dongthang.controller.AppDelegate.sendMessage(AppDelegate.java:35)
04-01 23:39:06.463: W/System.err(1932):     at edu.dongthang.controller.Controller.sendToAppDel(Controller.java:101)
```

when i click on error message

```
at edu.dongthang.controller.AppDelegate$ClientThread.sendMessage(AppDelegate.java:93)
```

pointer to the line

```
if (e.getMessage().equals("Network unreachable"))
```

on the method

```
public void sendMessage(String message) throws SocketException{
        try {
            buf = message.getBytes();
            if (buf != null) {
                DatagramPacket out = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length,
                        serverAddr, serverPort);
                socket.send(out);
                network_reachable = true;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ClientActivity", "Client Send Error:" + serverAddr + serverPort);
            if (e.getMessage().equals("Network unreachable")) {
                Log.e("ClientActivity", "Netork UNREACHABLE!!!!:");
                network_reachable = false;
            }
            closeSocketNoMessge();
        }


    }
```

I don't know why while i'm really have IP = 192.168.1.2 and port = 5444. so, the message is "network unreachable"

Answer (score 1):

1. According to the logs you posted, you have a `NullPointerException` - not a "network unreachable error". It looks like `e.getMessage()` is returning `null` (which is perfectly legal per [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage%28%29)). You need to check that value and not try to call `equals()` on it when it's `null`.
2. Judging by the `/192.168.1.2` in your log message, your remote IP is malformed - there shouldn't be a forward slash there. Try removing it.